# Get the MAX(value) using fiscal type years ie; 2016/2017, etc

Tags: sqlite

My calendar year runs from 07-01-(of one year) to 06-30-(of the next year).

My SQLITE DB has a Timestamp column and it's data type is datetime and stores the timestamp as 2023-09-01 00:00:00.

What I'm trying to do is get the MAX date of the latest snowfall. For example, with my seasonal years beginning July-01 (earliest) and ending June 30 (latest), I want to find only the latest (MAX) date snowfall was recorded, regardless of the year, based on the month.

Say if out of five years (2017 to 2022) worth of data in the database and it snowed Mar 15, 2020. And there was no date greater than than this one in any year, then this would be the latest date regardless which year it fell.

I've been trying many variations of the below query. This query says it runs with no mistakes and returns "null" values. I'm using SQLITE DB Browser to write and test the query.

```
SELECT Timestamp, MAX(strftime('%m-%d-%Y', Timestamp)) AS lastDate,
snowDepth AS lastDepth FROM DiaryData
WHERE lastDepth <> 0 BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Timestamp,'start of year', '+7 months')
AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Timestamp, 'start of year', '+1 year', '+7 months', '- 1 day')
ORDER BY lastDate LIMIT 1
```

and this is what's in my test database:

```
Timestamp          snowFalling  snowLaying  snowDepth
2021-11-10 00:00:00     0            0         7.2
2022-09-15 00:00:00     0            0         9.5
2022-12-01 00:00:00     1            0         2.15
2022-10-13 00:00:00     1            0         0.0
2022-05-19 00:00:00     0            0         8.82
2023-01-11 00:00:00     0            0         3.77
```

If it's running properly I should expect:

| Timestamp | lastDate | lastDepth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-19 00:00:00 | 05-19-2022 | 8.82 |

What am I missing or is this not possible in SQLITE? Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: this looks suspicious: `WHERE lastDepth <> 0 BETWEEN...`

Comment: On `2022-05-19 00:00:00` the column `snowFalling` is `0` which, I guess, implies there was no snowfall. Is this correct?

Comment: @topsail I fixed the scrolling issue. Why is this suspicious? WHERE lastDepth <> 0 BETWEEN

Comment: well, because lastdepth not equal to zero doesn't have to be between anything ... just zero or not zero. It looks weird to me. Of course it may just look weird to me, not be wrong.

Comment: @forpas -snowFalling and snowLaying are not utilized in the query.

Comment: @topsail - I'll give this a go and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: In the question you mention "latest **snowfall** of the season". How do you define *snowfall*?

Comment: @forpas -snowfall in this case is defined as the lastDepth which is amount of snow in inches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd get season for each record first, snowfall date relative to record's season start date after this, and largest snowfall date relative to record's season start date finally:

```sql
with
  data as (
    select
      *
    , case
        when cast(strftime('%m', "Timestamp") as int) <= 7
          then strftime('%Y-%m-%d', "Timestamp", 'start of year', '-1 year', '+6 months')
        else strftime('%Y-%m-%d', "Timestamp", 'start of year', '+6 months')
      end as "Season start date"
    from DiaryData

    where 1==1
    and "snowDepth" <> 0.0
  )

, data2 as (
    select
      *
    , julianday("Timestamp") - julianday("Season start date")
      as "Showfall date relative to season start date"
    from data
  )

, data3 as (
    select
      "Timestamp"
    , "snowFalling"
    , "snowLaying"
    , "snowDepth"
    from data2

    group by null
    having max("Showfall date relative to season start date")
  )
select
  *
from data3
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3iPARddcxZ17UxzCdBNz9x/2)

Comment: I understand most of your code but what does "WHERE 1==1" mean in this case.

Comment: After much testing of all these great answers (which all work) I determined @Adobe provided the one that met my needs the most. Thank you to everybody that provided answers to help me through my issue.

Comment: @surban21 I wonder what kind of testing you did. Here: https://dbfiddle.uk/XYZ9JJEP you can find the query plans of all 3 queries.

Comment: @forpas I tested on my project which is where any of these scripts will be run. I just happened to find that Adobe's worked for my needs the best. That doesn't mean I didn't learn from yours or the others. Isn't that why we ask for help? Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @surban21 Your needs are explained in your question. For these needs, the link I provided in my previous comment shows which is the most performant query and it is obvious just by taking a look which is the simplest. So, how does this query work for your *needs* best?

Comment: @forpas why can't you just accept my thanks for helping me? Just because I decided to go with Adobe's does not mean yours won't be useful for other queries I may have later down the road.

Comment: @surban21 you can accept any answer that you want. I asked what kind of tests you did that proved that this query is better for the requirement described in your question (because all we know is what exists in your question). My testing about performance does not justify your decision. The complexity of this query also does not justify your decision. Any user who will come this thread with the same problem will wonder what makes this query better. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: @forpas I'm obviously a novice at coding as I don't understand the whats or hows things work, but I'm learning. So the more things work for me without much fiddling the better. Plus I may not frame questions perfectly because I sometimes don't know how to ask the question due to lack of coding experience. As far as your code, it initially worked as needed, but if I took out the 05-19-2023 entry, next up should be 01-11-2023; instead yours was 11-10-2021.  The last snow dates should work backwards. For example; start with Jun 30 2022 working backward to July 01 2021. Adobe's did this for me.

Comment: @surban21 there is no 2023-05-19 entry in your sample data. There is 2022-05-19 and 2023-01-11 belongs to a different fiscal year.

Comment: @forpas okay, typo on the date. Meant 19-05-2022. In my original question for help I put this "What I'm trying to do is get the MAX date in my fiscal years of the latest snowfall of the season over all years in the db." Maybe this wasn't worded clearly, but what I meant was, encompassing all the years regardless of whether the latest date was in 2021 or in 2023 based on my previous comment about working backward from June 30 to July 01.

Comment: @surban21 `where 1==1` is just for readability: to put each "filtering condition" on a separate line. It can be replaced with `where "snowDepth" <> 0.0`.

Comment: @surban21 Both mine and lemon's queries return 1 row for each fiscal year. If this is not what you asked for, then why did you leave comments that both queries worked? Nothing makes sense in your explanations.

Comment: @forpas BECAUSE THEY DID INITIALLY! DONE!

Comment: @surban21 if your requirement is different than what you asked for then both queries did not work neither initially nor now. What is DONE is that you waste contributor's time by misleading questions and comments.

Answer (score 3):

Use aggregation by fiscal year utilizing [SQLite's feature of bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query):

```
SELECT Timestamp, 
       strftime('%m-%d-%Y', MAX(Timestamp)) AS lastDate, 
       snowDepth AS lastDepth 
FROM DiaryData
WHERE snowDepth <> 0
GROUP BY strftime('%Y', Timestamp, '+6 months');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kn9TPb0O).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function to address this problem, yet need to apply a subtle tweak. In order to account for fiscal years, you can partition on the year for timestamps slided 6 months further. In this way, ranges like [2021-01-01, 2021-12-31] will instead be slided to [2021-06-01, 2022-05-31].

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  PARTITION BY STRFTIME('%Y', DATE(Timestamp_, '+6 months')) 
                  ORDER     BY Timestamp_ DESC           ) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT Timestamp_, 
       STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', Timestamp_) AS lastDate,
       snowDepth                        AS lastDepth
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4nDTvWtLG7jNay1vcQHNy1/2).

Comment: I'll play around with this. My mind gets all muddled up with this fiscal year stuff. :) Thanks @lemon